# Javascript file inside iFrame do not get executed when iFrame refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there any reason why the javascript file ( **app.js** ) which is used inside my iframe do not get executed when my iFrame refreshes?

Basically what's happening now is:
When I first load **index.html** , the javascript **app.js** output "hello world" to the console, but then once the iframe gets automatically refreshed ( through **reloader.js** ) everything refreshes but the javascript, what I mean is, once the iframe is refreshed I don't get a new "hello world".

Does anyone passed through the same issue?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>treedux - Development Server</title>
    <script src="reloader.js"></script>

    <script>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="icon-menu"></div>
        3dux.io Header
    </div>
    <iframe id="treeduxwrapper" class="iframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>treedux - Development Server</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="icon-menu"></div>
        CONTENT
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
console.log('hello world')
```

Thanks in advance,
TF

Comment: Can you show the code of `reloader.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reload by this,

```
document.getElementById('treeduxwrapper').contentWindow.location.href = "iframe.html"
```

Comment: That did! Although I'm little bit confused on why setting the src of frame do not work...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you have kept your reloader.js in the index.html which will reload the current page(index.html) only, not the iframe.html. So in short your iframe.html is not getting reload on every reload of index.html.